# INSERTED, UPDATED and DELETE tables not recording NULL values

Tags: sql-server, triggers, audit

I have create a table and a column of one of this table can accept null values. this table can be found below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Locations](
    [location_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [location_Code] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [location_Name] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Locations] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [location_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I created a trigger for this table so that when i insert, update or delete a record from this table, i will be able to audit the old record and new record. the below is the code that i am using:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM   inserted) 
      BEGIN 
          IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM   deleted) 
            BEGIN 
                ...
            END 
          ELSE 
            BEGIN 
                SET @NewValues = (SELECT * FROM inserted FOR XML AUTO);
                SET @XXXID = (SELECT location_ID FROM inserted);
                SET @Type = 'INSERT'; -- Row has been inserted 
            END 
      END 
    ELSE 
      ...
```

The problem is that when i insert or update a record and the value of the column Code is null, the inserted table will only contain the values of the other two column. in other words, the null value is ignored:

```
<inserted location_ID="1" location_Name="Malta"/>
```

Is there a way how i can get the null value as well i.e. i get the below XML:

```
<inserted location_ID="1" location_Name="Malta"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your trigger is broken. `inserted` (and `deleted`) can contain *multiple* rows (or no rows). So `SET @XXXID = (SELECT user_ID FROM inserted);` will break.

Comment: Nothing strange with the generated XML. NULL means no value for the attribute, ie no attribute. Anything else would result in *invalid* XML - how else would you represent an attribute with a null value? If you want a different XML you have to specify its format explicitly. Anyway,  instead of hand-coding auditing, check SQL Server's own audit mechanisms or even Change Tracking.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever 
with the IF statement that i have just made, the inserted table can never be null but as you said correctly, it can contain multiple rows (which i didnt know)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
thanks. i will try to use SQL Server's own audit mechanisms and Change Tracking

Comment: thanks both of you for your help :)